# Get unread emails in C# from Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

Hi I need to fetch unread emails. Is the last few lines correct as it is throwing an exception when `i` is 0 - Array index out of bounds.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items oItems = myInbox.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = true");

for(int i = 0; i <= oItems.Count; i++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = ( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems[i];
    textEmail.Text += "\r\nSubject:" + oMsg.Subject.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `i <= oItems.Count` should be `i < oItems.Count`... it's entering the loop even when count is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items collection's index starts from 1. (probably due to legacy + VBA influence of Exchange Objects)

Hence you need to either start your counter from 1 or use the for each loop. (also your end index check was wrong)

```
// index starts from 1.
for(int i = 1; i <= oItems.Count; i++)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = ( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oItems[i];
    textEmail.Text += "\r\nSubject:" + oMsg.Subject.ToString();
}
```

the other option is to use a foreach loop which is slightly slower than a for loop, but works almost equivalently for all practical purposes.

```
// var doesn't work for these com based legacy object models.
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg in oItems)
{
    textEmail.Text += "\r\nSubject:" + oMsg.Subject.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a foreach loop instead

```
foreach (var item in oItems)
{
   textEmail.Text += "\r\nSubject:" + item.Subject.ToString();
}
```

...

Comment: for 'Subject' and no extension method 'Subject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)